# NodeJS Mocha unit testing with global injected variables from WebPack.DefinePlugin

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js

Global variables injected via the WebPack.DefinePlugin don't seem to mesh well with my Mocha unit tests. The global variables aren't recognised when running the test and the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/) doesn't appear to have a way to inject these global variables.

How do I inject these variables such that they'll work in the unit test?

### Detailed description

Given a WebPack project with the following configuration:

```
{
    ...
    plugins: [
        ...
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __ENV__: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENVIRONMENT),
            ...
        }),
        ...
    ]
}
```

And having the following typescript code in my project:

```
declare let __ENV__: string;

...

export const ENV = __ENV__;
```

If I run Mocha with the following options:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register --require ./test/entry.ts **/*.test.ts
```

Mocha will run into the following error:

```
C:\git\project\src\constants\config.ts:7
export const ENV = __ENV__;
                   ^
ReferenceError: __ENV__ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\git\project\src\constants\config.ts:7:20)
    ...
```

### What I tried

I figured I should define `__ENV__` in my `entry.ts` file. The following attempts all failed with various errors when running mocha:

```
const __ENV__ = 'dev'; // Same message as above.
window.__ENV__ = 'dev'; // Property '__ENV__' does not exist on type 'Window'.
window['__ENV__'] = 'dev'; // ReferenceError: window is not defined
global.__ENV__ = 'dev'; // Property '__ENV__' does not exist on type 'Global'.
export declare let __ENV__ = 'dev'; // Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
export declare const __ENV__ = 'dev'; // Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

Comment: Were you manage to solve this?

Comment: Sorry @deathangel908 but no. I switched to using `Jest` and also avoid using `WebPack.DefinePlugin`. Now (because it's a webapp) I use code-behind to populate a `window` object and then in my `Jest` setup I define a test `window` object in `beforeAll()`.

Comment: Damn. Same problem. :(

Answer (score 2):

### ✨ Whoohoo

I have solved this using https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874686/5244937 .

#### > index.ts

This is my central env place. I have two classes (DevTool, EmptyProdTool) implementing different behaviour for DEV vs PROD.

This is usually replaced by webpack.

```
import { DevTool } from "./dev";
import { EmptyProdTool } from "./prod";

declare global {
  /** https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874686/5244937 */
  var __IS_DEV__: boolean;
  var __IS_PROD__: boolean;
}

export interface ENVClass {
  dev_log(message: any): void;
  dev_error(message: any): void;
  backgroundColor: string;
  isDev: boolean;
  isProd: boolean;
}

export const ENV = __IS_DEV__ ? new DevTool() : new EmptyProdTool();
```

#### > webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [

    ...

      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __IS_DEV__: JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV == "development"),
        __IS_PROD__: JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV == "production")
      }),
    
    ...

    ]
```

#### > tests/_env_injection.ts

This replaces the injection of  `__IS_DEV__` and `__ID_PROD__` for mocha tests.

```
/** https://stackoverflow.com/a/62874686/5244937 */
globalThis.__IS_DEV__ = true;
globalThis.__IS_PROD__ = false;
```

#### > package.json > starting mocha & ts-node without webpack

```
  "scripts": {

    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register --require test/_env_injection.ts test/**/*.spec.ts",

    }
```