# How to declare in initialize global variable in TS-Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

With Webpack:

```js
const WebpackConfig = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new Webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: isDevelopmentBuildingMode,
      __IS_TESTING_BUILDING_MODE__: isTestingBuildingMode,
      __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__: !isDevelopmentBuildingMode && !isTestingBuildingMode
    })
  ]
}
```

Now I'm going to use TS-Node instead of Webpack. TS-Node does not see these constants:

```
ErrorsReportingService.ts:35:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__'.
```

How to initialize these globals for TS-Node?

Off course, typings for these constants are being provided:

```
declare const __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
declare const __IS_TESTING_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
declare const __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
```

Please note that I need both Webpack and TSNode.

### Solution on conceptual level

1. Create file and initialize global variables (like `globalThis.__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ = false` ?)
2. Tell TSNode to execute this file first.

Now the question is TSNode allows such things or not.

### Update

My TypeScript lost the declared globals after I placed them inside `declare global {}`:

**typings.d.ts**

```js
declare global {
  let __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
  let __IS_TESTING_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
  let __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
}
```

Now compiler does not see them:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name '__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__'.
```

[image]

Comment: Its weird to say instead - its just you drop webpack and ask for a way to add its behaviour? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript

Comment: @Estradiaz because I need both Webpack and TSNode.

Comment: Hmm maybe I missunderstod your issue, so you want to use those but typescript complains even though you provide those declarations in a .d.ts file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1: Make TypeScript aware of your globals**

The canonical way to define globals that exist both in Node.js and on the server is to use the `var` keyword.

```
declare global {
  var __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
  var __IS_TESTING_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
  var __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MORE__: boolean;
}
```

This makes them accessible via `globalThis` and by referencing them directly.

```
globalThis.__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__;
__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__;
```

**Step 2: Define them on the client**

That's what `Webpack.DefinePlugin` is already doing for you.

**Step 3: Define them on the server**

Find the entry point of your Node application and define the variable there.

```
var __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ = true;
```

A common practice is to use environment variables.

```
var __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am sorry, my TypeScript lost the declared globals (`Cannot find name '__IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__`) after I placed them inside `declare global {}`. I updated my answer. Maybe I missed something in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: In order for it to work, it must be located in a _module_, that is a file with at least one import/export statement. Make sure to put your `declare global` block in a file like that, or add an empty export statement like `export {}` to the file it's currently in.

Answer (score 0):

one way here is you can use a class here like.

```
export class Config{
/*add field like this*/
 __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
 __IS_TESTING_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
 const __IS_PRODUCTION_BUILDING_MODE__: boolean;
}
```

and then use in your code using import like.

```
import {Config} from 'your file location'
Config.your_variable_name
```